# Will HD Voice feature on an unlocked Lumia 1020 work on T-Mobile USA network?

Tags: functionality, cellular

I made a phone call the other day on my friend's Lumia 920, calling another Lumia 920, both on the T-Mobile USA network.  The clarity of my other friend's voice on the phone call was quite impressive.

I could buy a 920 of my own from T-Mobile, but alternatively, I'm also considering whether a Lumia 1020 would be worth having.  Unfortunately, T-Mobile itself does not sell 1020s. I would have to buy one from another retailer and use it on the T-Mobile network.

The HD Voice question is a critical factor in deciding whether to buy a 1020.  Would HD Voice would work on the unlocked 1020?

Comment: Perhaps this is really a question about T-Mobile, not Windows Phone.

Comment: It should but I can't verify it. The Lumia 1020 support HD Voice (it's an extra voice codec most phones support) and as long as you have the correct T-Mobile settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Nokia Lumia (probably all Windows Phone devices too) support HD Voice.

HD Voice is a standard so yes it would work on your unlocked phone.

Comment: My current phone, Lumia 710 (WP 7.5) does not support HD Voice.  Perhaps all WP 8 phones support it, but this older one does not.